# Computing SD for function of two RV's in R gives wrong results

Tags: r, variance, standard-deviation, random-variable

I have 2 random variables, all independant, discrete and uniform

I want to compute standard deviation for Z = X - Y

Here is the R code:

```
#create X and Y
X = rep(0:1, c(733-41,41))
Y = rep(0:1, c(742-60,60))

#create Z as Y - X
Z = c()
for (i in X) {Z = c(Z,c(Y-i))}
```

Means are equal:

```
mean(Z)
[1] 0.02492802
mean(Y) - mean(X)
[1] 0.02492802
```

Then I count standard deviation and variance of Z using the formula:

```
sd(Y) + sd(X)
[1] 0.5027599
var(Y) + var(X)
[1] 0.1273021
```

Ann then, using sd() and var() functions:

```
sd(Z)
[1] 0.3565528
var(Z)
[1] 0.1271299
```

Where is my mistake and why sd(Y) + sd(X) != sd(Z) and var(Z) != var(Y) + var(X)?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52534, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26886, etc.

Comment: I don't see `e` defined anywhere. Is `Z` supposed to be `c(X, Y)`? That doesn't seem to be the way you created it.

Comment: Sorry mate, e is Z actually, I fixed it.